# populating a matrix in vba

Tags: matrix, populate

I'm trying to populate a matrix from three columns in a worksheet. My code is supposed to find a value in the first column, match it to the y-axis, then search the second column for a value, match it to a column header in the x-axis, and then paste the value from the third column in the cell activated by the row/column match. Does anyone see what's wrong with my code? I keep getting a "object variable or with block variable not set" error:

Sub Button1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim strMatchJE As String
Dim strMatchComponent As String
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wBook1 As Workbook

Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Activate Journal Entry Number
strMatchJE = Columns("A").Find(what:="", after:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
aString = Left(originalString, 1)

strMatchJE = wSheet.Cells.Find(what:=aString, after:=Wbook.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Address

'Activate component
strMatchComponent = Columns("B").Find(what:="", after:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
bString = Left(originalString, 1)

strMatchJE = wSheet.Cells.Find(what:=aString, after:=Wbook.Cells(2, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Address

strEnterAmount = Columns("T").Find(what:="", after:=wSheet.Cells(3, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate

firstrow = ActiveCell.Row
firstcolumn2 = ActiveCell.Column

firstrow = firstrow + 1

Rows(firstrow).Columns(firstcolumn2).Select
strEnterAmount.Paste
```

End Sub